# Tikz: Text not centered within Tikz boxes

Tags: tikz-styles, alignment, mathcha

I'm trying to construct a flow chart type diagram using tikzpicture package (Mathcha). Why is the text within Tikz boxes not centered? Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\vspace{4ex}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,634); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 634

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp08909796923277336] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (51,41) -- (609,41) -- (609,81) -- (51,81) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp293971635997501] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (210,359.72) -- (520,359.72) -- (520,401.3) -- (210,401.3) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp015112508692092352] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (190,210.2) -- (310,210.2) -- (310,250) -- (190,250) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp9224449615071879] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (490,209.82) -- (610,209.82) -- (610,250.13) -- (490,250.13) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da2085806199614264] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (550,249.95) -- (550,379.8) -- (525,380.07) ;
\draw [shift={(521,380.12)}, rotate = 359.37] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6918276956657493] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (180,81.59) -- (180,149.45) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8143556798116779] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (110,250.35) -- (110,310.21) -- (250,310.01) -- (250,249.93) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6498353350246521] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (180,310.11) -- (180,379.97) -- (205,380.35) ;
\draw [shift={(209,380.42)}, rotate = 180.89] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp6903312621520653] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (50,210.2) -- (170,210.2) -- (170,250) -- (50,250) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6819495654480933] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (110,209.57) -- (110,149.57) -- (250,149.68) -- (250,209.87) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4777805352746255] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (400,81.72) -- (400,205.1) ;
\draw [shift={(400,209.1)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6994702521621938] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (480,310.37) -- (480,354.55) ;
\draw [shift={(480,358.55)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5755824703070298] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (400,250.37) -- (400,354.55) ;
\draw [shift={(400,358.55)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da11378713626826986] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (550,81.72) -- (550,205.1) ;
\draw [shift={(550,209.1)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp2737101017997946] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (340,209.82) -- (460,209.82) -- (460,250.13) -- (340,250.13) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp04718661092413878] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (430,270.07) -- (530,270.07) -- (530,309.88) -- (430,309.88) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da40081723928825497] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (400,290.1) -- (425,290.1) ;
\draw [shift={(429,290.1)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (11.61,-5.58) -- (0,0) -- (11.61,5.58) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (181,52) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {High Position on Alphabetically Ordered List};
% Text Node
\draw (348,222) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {Higher Visibility};
% Text Node
\draw (445,281) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {Familiarity};
% Text Node
\draw (57,222.18) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {Status quo bias};
% Text Node
\draw (251,371.18) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {Higher Trading Activity + Liquiditiy};
% Text Node
\draw (495,222) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {Superior Quality};
% Text Node
\draw (215,222.18) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=center] {Satisficing};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The text is actually centered in the nodes, but the nodes (which don't have a border) are not place exactly in the center of the rectangles that are meant to be the border of the nodes. It might be better to create this from scratch, if you really just need such a simple diagram.

Comment: @Jude123 In the long run it will safe you a lot of time if you now take a couple of minutes to read a TikZ introduction instead of having to deal with this horrible code mathcha produces.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks for the explanation. I thought Mathcha was a practical tool, but if it produces such awful codes, I better learn how to deal with TikZ and draw on my own.

Comment: Maybe you can improve the code Mathcha produces, but since I don't know the software, I cannot really tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the text in the nodes is not centered is actually, that what looks like nodes (the black rectangles) are indeed just that: black rectangles. The text is then positioned later using nodes that have no borders. Sady, these nodes are not positioned properly in the center of the rectangles.

I would recommend that you don't use this horrible output produced by some software, but instead try to understand how to deal with Ti*k*Z and draw this on your own. I know that the Ti*k*Z/PGF manual is huge and intimidating, but it also contains some nice tutorials that explain the basic stuff nicely. Just keep it at a slow pace, it really pays off and you will quickly get familiar with the syntax.

The shown diagram could drawn as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=1.75cm,
    y=1.75cm,
    line width=1pt,
    >=latex,
    every node/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        inner ysep=10pt,
        text width=3cm,
        align=center,
    },
    narrow/.append style={
        text width=2cm,
    },
    wide/.append style={
        text width=7cm,
    },
    very wide/.append style={
        text width=13.5cm,
    },
]

\node[very wide] at (0,0) (a1) {\textbf{High Position on Alphabetically Ordered List}};

\node at (-3,-2) (b1) {Status quo bias};
\node at (-1,-2) (b2) {Satisficing};
\node at (1,-2) (b3) {Higher Visibility};
\node at (3,-2) (b4) {Superior Quality};

\node[narrow] at (2,-2.75) (c1) {Familiarity};

\node[wide] at (0.5,-4) (d1) {\textbf{Higher Trading Activity $+$ Liquidity}};

\draw (-2,-1 |- a1.south) -- (-2,-1);
\draw (-2,-1) -| (b1.north);
\draw (-2,-1) -| (b2.north);

\draw (b1.south) |- (-2,-3);
\draw (b2.south) |- (-2,-3);
\draw[->] (-2,-3) |- (d1.west);

\draw[->] (b3.north |- a1.south) -- (b3.north);
\draw[->] (b4.north |- a1.south) -- (b4.north);

\draw[->] (b3.south) -- (b3.south |- d1.north);
\draw[->] (b3.south |- c1.west) -- (c1.west);
\draw[->] (c1.south) -- (c1.south |- d1.north);
\draw[->] (b4.south) |- (d1.east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]